# Changing the format of DATETIME property in winform C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, datetime-format

What's wrong with this code?

```
Client c = new Client();
string format = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
string dateAdded = now.ToString(format);
c.RegistrationDate = DateTime.Parse(dateAdded);
```

c.RegistrationDate is a dateTime object in the client class and I want it to insert to my database.

However It doesn't convert the freaking date to the format in my mysql database. It always says that string format is incorrect. WHAT have i done wrong???? should I convert my Registration Date to string??? Thanks

**EDIT: Sorry I've forgot to mention. "now" is `now = DateTime.Now;` it gets the current time of the date and time.

Comment: What type is your `now` variable?  If it's a `DateTime`, then why are you converting it to a `string` and then back into a `DateTime` with `DateTime.Parse()`?

Comment: because I want to convert it's format so I guess I should have converted it first to a string to change its format and change its type ^^. but I failed...

Comment: As Jon Skeet already pointed out, a `DateTime` doesn't *have* a format, it's just a value. If you want a formatted string, then you want a `string`, not a `DateTime`, so you don't need `DateTime.Parse()` at all.

Comment: @DanielPryden: Sir does that mean that I shouldn't have a DateTime object in my Client Class? Should I change its datatype to a string instead? Thanks...

Comment: Not necessarily.  If you are *using* the `DateTime` value to build a string, then *that* code should be using `c.RegistrationDate.ToString(format)`.  You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding about the difference between a **value** and a **representation of that value**.  As a simple example, the number 42 is a value, and `"42"`, `"forty-two"` and `"XLII"` are all *representations* of that same value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `DateTime` doesnt *have* a format - it's just the date/time. (Whether it's local time, UTC or whatever is a different matter, mind you.)

Firstly, you shouldn't be converting to and from text like you are: that's just a recipe for trouble. Just use:

```
c.RegistrationDate = now;
```

... performing any rounding you need to.

You haven't shown how you're trying to insert the value into your database. If you're including the value in the SQL statement *directly*, that would explain it. You should be using a *parameterized SQL statement* and passing the value directly in the parameter - no conversion necessary.

If you're already doing that, please show us the code you're trying to use to insert the data, and we'll see what we can do. See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-parameters) for some examples.

Comment: Thank you for answering mr. But if I try to use that, the format that I am sending to my database doesn't match the format in my database. It gives me an error. T_T I have also a registrationdate in my db which is a datetime format but its format is yyyy/MM/dd. xD

Comment: @rjtubera: If it really is a date/time field in the database, you shouldn't need to care about formats. It should be absolutely fine if you use parameters - if that gives you an error, then *say what the error is*. We can't help you if you don't give us information.

Comment: It gives me an "Incorrect datetime value: '2/14/2012 8:10:35 AM' for column 'dateAdded' at row 1" the 2/14/2012 (day/month/year) is what I am sending to the database but what the database wants is (year/month/day) format.

Comment: Sir Unfortunately, I am not implementing that parameterized SQL as I am still learning the language. I'm very very sorry. T_T

Comment: @rjtubera: But parameterized SQL is simply the right thing to do. Learn to do the right thing, rather than trying to work around it. Without parameterized SQL, you'll be inviting SQL injection attacks as soon as you have any user-entered text. SQL parameters aren't terribly difficult, and it's better not to get into bad habits.

Comment: So does that mean that I can't solve my problem without using parameterized SQL. is there any other way mr.? PLEASE!! PLEASE!

Comment: @rjtubera: You *could* just use `ToString` with the right format string but you **shouldn't**. Why are you so vehemently against doing the right thing? I've linked to the documentation which gives you an example of it. It will save you a *lot* of anguish in the long run if you just spend 5 minutes learning to do it right now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong with the c# code,except I assume you must be doing

```
string dateAdded = DateTime.Now.ToString(format);
```

Otherwise I am not sure what 'now' is.